# Google App Engine does not parse JSF 2.0 tags

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2

I have a problem with running JSF 2.0 on AppEngine. I have following `index.xhtml` and if I deploy it and open the page, there is nothing but the **Title** and the page's source code is completely the same as it was written - no changes from `<h:head>` to `<head>` whatsoever.

`index.xhtml`

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:inputText value="Text"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

`appengine-web.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>app</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
    <system-properties>
            <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>    
</appengine-web-app>
```

`web.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
<display-name>Task Manager</display-name>
<description>Internal task manager</description>

<!-- Seems like GAE 1.2.6 cannot handle server side session management. 
    At least for JSF 2.0.1 -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Recommendation from GAE pages -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- ***** Accommodate Single-Threaded Requirement of Google AppEngine -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- ***** Load the JavaServer Faces Servlet ***** -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- ***** Specify session timeout of thirty (30) minutes. ***** -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Stacktrace after the change**

```
W 2011-06-25 03:13:11.763
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-32c47fe3ad43decc(Request.java)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:422)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:573)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

E 2011-06-25 03:13:11.766
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:260)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9673)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:422)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:573)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

W 2011-06-25 03:13:11.768
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@11d2066{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~cse-info/1.351380543505614038}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:260)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9673)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:422)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:573)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

C 2011-06-25 03:13:11.775
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:211)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:260)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9673)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:422)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:573)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically happens if a request is not handled by the Faces Servlet and has is not specifically about GAE.

What URL did you used to access your page? Since you declared a prefix mapping, you have to insert /faces/ into your URLs, e.g. my.appspot.com/faces/mypage.xhtml.

I would recommend going for suffix mapping and using .xhtml exclusively:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>      
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Haha, answered at the same time. I'm downtown this noon, so you have all freedom here then :)

Comment: That was really the problem. But I got an ugly stacktrace after the fix which I don't understand to. All libraries should be there...

Comment: You might have packaged more libs in your war than necessary. For JSF (mojarra) you only need two libs the jsf-impl en jsf-api ones. A quick guess is that you packaged something from the Servlet api along. Also, don't forget to read the manuals about how to use JSF 2 with GAE. JSF 2.1.x doesn't seem to run (couple of months ago) and for JSF 2.0.x I still needed a patch (also a couple of months ago). Maybe it's different again now, but read the latest how-to's.

Comment: I read the GAE's manual and followed the instructions. But I'm going to try the JSF 2.0.x instead of JSF 2.1.x and see what happens.

Comment: JSF 2.1.x is known not to work since it doesn't work on Jetty, which is what GAE is using. I guess you're reading this document: https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/sun-javaserver-faces-reference-implementation/configuring-jsf-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine Additionally, you may need to do what's mentioned here: http://javadocs.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/mojarra-jsf-2-0-rc2-and-google-app-engine-sdk-1-2-6/ It's not in the main guide but I needed it before JSF would work.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the request URL as you've in the browser address bar does not match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml`. It's the one responsible for parsing the Facelet file, creating the `FacesContext` and doing all the JSF works.

You have mapped the `FacesServlet` on `/faces/*`, so that means that you've to include `/faces/` after the context path in the request URL to get it to run. I.e.

> http://example.com/contextpath/faces/index.xhtml

Alternatively, you can also change the URL pattern to

```xml
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

so that all XHTML (Facelet) files will be parsed by `FacesServlet` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for [MyFaces and GAE Support](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/googleappenginesupport.html). It has some hints about how to setup correctly this environment and if you need more information you can suscribe to [MyFaces Users Mailing List](http://myfaces.apache.org/mail-lists.html). To see a running example using JSF on GAE check this link [MyFaces HTML5 Demo](http://bit.ly/myfaces-html5-demo)

Comment: I'm only mentioning a possible option well tested that works. Look on this link [MYFACES-2504](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-2504). Your other alternative is change Mojarra's code. Good luck!

Comment: In fact, look on Mojarra issue tracker these issues related to GAE: [JAVASERVERFACES-1886](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1886), [JAVASERVERFACES-1245](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1245), [JAVASERVERFACES-1885](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1885)

Comment: 1885 is an unfortunate problem. The thing I don't understand is why this isn't being mentioned in most JSF/GAE howtos. It seems impossible that for some people 'it just works'. Anyway, if anyone is bothered by this too: please vote for these issues. Thanks ;)

Comment: It looks like that JSF on GAE brings more problems that benefits. Is there any better framework for the web layer which definitely works, is easy to use and supports AJAX?

Comment: GAE impose a lot of restrictions about which code is valid and which one is not, specially by security reasons. It is common to find code that works standalone but not on GAE, so any other available framework should possibly make modifications to work correctly. Don't blame JSF, because there is at least one implementation that runs on GAE (MyFaces), so it is not an specification problem, it is a problem on the web framework implementation, and its will to be GAE friendly.

Comment: @lu4242: If MyFaces really work, I'll try them. The HTML5 demo is very slow, but I guess that if I'll use old HTML4, there will be no problems.